# Как вывести название элемента в хлебных крошках?

Tags: битрикс, breadcrumbs

Всем привет !

Есть сайт, на котором выводятся новости, компонентом news. У инфоблока новостей есть свойство - привязка к элементам, по которому выводится новости по конкретному элементу. Ссылка на страницу с новостями по конкретному элементу имеет вид(****.ru/news/ - страница со всеми новостями):

****.ru/news/?POSELOK_ID=135

Так же, с помощью breadcrumb выводится навигационная цепочка. Нужно на странице новостей по элементу в навигационную цепочку выводить название элемента, что то вроде такого:

https://prnt.sc/rla9ve

Буду рад любой помощи :)

Answer (score 0):

У компонента [bitrix:news.detail](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news_detail.php) есть настройка - выводить название и заголовки. Если компонент кастомизированный или не нравится как выводит в хлебные крошки, то Вам нужно использовать [AddChainItem](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/addchainitem.php) в коде компонента для добавления пункта хлебной крошки.